# Withdraw a flag? Or let the moderator figure it out?

Tags: support, flags

I have a bunch of tabs open and accidentally flagged the wrong post as spam

Accidentally Flagged:

[Anitvirus says my program is suspicious](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11006947/anitvirus-says-my-program-is-suspicious)

Actual Spam:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11006980/how-to-reset-windows-7-password

I see that there is no feature to withdraw a flag.  What's the appropriate protocol?  Raise another "Other" flag informing the moderator what I did?  Just let him figure it out?

Comment: Why is that "actual spam"?

Comment: Because it links to a website that sells a solution to the question, windowsloginrecovery dot com.

Comment: But oopps, had the labels reversed :-)  Fixed.

Comment: Here is another "Leo Green" post you can flag as spam into oblivion:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/10941968/552792. Same situation, same link, except posted as an answer that doesn't actually answer the question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no way to un-flag a post, unfortunately. However, the post you flagged most likely will not accrue any additional spam flags. While the moderator may spend some time trying to figure out *why* someone marked it as spam, a moderator who looks at your flag will most likely decline the flag and take no actions.

One thing you could do is leave a comment on the post saying that you accidentally flagged the post but didn't mean to. This would help the moderator quickly figure out that no actions are needed. After reviewing the flag, the moderator should delete your comment.

You could also see if a moderator is active in a chat room, in which case you could give that person a link to the post.

Lastly, you should know that the system only takes action on posts when the number of spam flags reaches a certain threshold. One flag shouldn't do any permanent damage. In the future, just be sure you're flagging the right post ;)

Comment: *"In the future, just be sure you're flagging the right post ;)"* I flagged an answer as "not an answer", but after it was edited it became a proper answer. That is a scenario in which it would be great if I would be able to withdraw the flag.